# What servo-motor (torque, power) is you think needed to rotate shower faucet?

Tags: stepper-motor, servo

Also how do you think you could create electronically controlled faucet?

I know that there exists magnetic valves, but they consume power all the time they operate, whereas I want a solution that would consume power only when changing amount of hot and cold water.

I have some ideas where the rotor in stepping motor have holes to cold and hot water and by rotating it you could change amount of cold and hot water but maybe there is ready to use solutions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mechanical engineering concerns

Comment: Unless you need a particular operating speed, it really depends on the mechanical advantage.  A stepper does have the advantages of being less likely to damage the value (and more likely to simply fail to actuate) and being able to still operate by hand when unpowered, but you probably need an encoder or at minimum limit switches to track position.  You may want to use timing belts for the connection, though large 3D printed plastic gears can be fun to experiment with (ie, parametric reprap extruder gears adjusted to need) at least for the cold water side.

Comment: Consider also [Robotics.SE](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/) if you want to ask specific questions about the mechanics involved connecting an actuator to a valve.

Answer (score 2):

Servos for the hobby RC market range from a few kg/cm to 40 kg/cm or more. For example, I am using a [Savox SC-0251](http://www.savoxusa.com/Savox_SC0251MG_Digital_Servo_p/savsc0251mg.htm) for a project. It is rated for ~16 kg/cm which means that at 1 cm from the shaft, it can push/pull 16 kg.

I doubt that a faucet requires that much force at the end of the handle, but of course, if you connect a linkage to the end of the faucet handle, you'll only get a small amount of travel.

You need to determine the amount of force needed to turn the valve at the position where your linkage connects, and decide if there is an appropriate servo. Unfortunately force meters can be quite expensive. You might just experiment with different servos to see what works, if you have access to a few.

Comment: OK. You've problably right.

Comment: You can probably rig up a horizontal rod to the shower handle (using clamps or tape) and hang weights until the handle starts to turn. The torque will be the distance from the weights to the pivot point of the handle times the force of the weights. Of course, you'd probably want to pick a motor that can deliver much more than that torque for the system to be effective.